Can I make azure applications upgrade automatically when deploying a new scaleset bicep?
I have a bicep that creates a VM scaleset while also deploying a VM application from a gallery. That works great.
After adding a new version of the VM application to the gallery, I rerun the scaleset bicep and ask it to install the latest version of the app.
When I look in the azure portal on the scaleset, the new version is listed under Extensions + Applications and it says success on Install Status.
However when I log onto the VM the new app has not been installed. In fact it hasn't even been downloaded to the VM. I can only see the original VM Application.
Am I missing something? Why does it claim to have successfully installed the new version when it hasn't even tried? Does application deployment only work when the scaleset is created? If so what is the best way to trigger an update of the VM app?
Bicep looks something like this:
applicationProfile: {
  galleryApplications: [
    {
      packageReferenceId: resourceId(applicationGalleryRG, 'Microsoft.Compute/galleries/applications/versions', applicationDepsGallery, myApp, myAppVersion)
      treatFailureAsDeploymentFailure: false
    }


Can you provide the complete code? @Bub
